# How to Create an Instance of the Class without "new" Keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

This project is NodeJS project with TypeScript.

I want to create an instance of App class. But, if I use `new` keyword, I have to pass constructor parameter.

The problem is that constructor parameter should be passed with dependency injection. So, I can't use `new` keyword to create an instance.

```
// Express
import { application as app } from 'express';

// Controllers
import { UserController } from './controllers/user.controller'

export class App {
  constructor(userController: UserController) {
    console.log("App is running");
    console.log("UserController url path is : ", userController.getUrlPath);

    this.run();
  }

  run(): void {
    app.listen(3000, function () {
      console.log('App is running on port 3000!');
    });
  }

  check(): void {
    console.log("working well");
  }
}

const appInstance: App = <App>Object.create(App.prototype); // it is not creating

console.log( appInstance.check() ); // ==> 'undefined'
```

Comment: You want to instantiate it without calling the constructor? This seems very weird to me. Can't you instantiate the UserController first, and pass it in when constructing the App class?

Comment: @JustusRomijn The problem is that UserController's contructor has some parameters. And the parameters's constructors have parameters. So, It is like : new App(new UserController(new UserRepository(new BaseRepository(new BlaBla))))

Comment: The parameters should come with dependency injection(automatically). But I cant create this App class.

Comment: Omitting `new` is not your solution. When using dependency injection you still have to create those dependencies first with ‘new’. Or you can use a separate class that manages your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to go against the very concept of using classes
If you need to avoid passing a concrete `UserController` for testing purposes, you can use some form of mock.
Another option is to use a variable of type `any`:

```
const app = new App({} as any);
```

Depending on your `tsconfig.json` configuration, it should work (obviously you won't be able to access any of the functions/fields of the `UserController` object, but the construction of `App` should work just fine.
The last option (I could think of at least) is using a setter function for the `UserController`:

```
export class App {
 private _userController: UserController;
 get userController(): UserController {
  return this._userController;
 }
 set userController(ctrl: UserController) {
  this._userController = ctrl;
 }
}
```

And this way, after setting up a full DI infrastructure, you can use `App.userController = SOME_USER_CONTROLLER_FROM_DI`